# React-Navigation and creation/destroy os screens/components

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have my app with some screens. One of these screens is called "Race". This race produce a ListView with current race ranking (came from Redux state). This same screen has a TCP connection component which connect to my sensor and get data (async).

When user click on rank item, a new screen is opened with current lap's from clicked racer (item on ListView). At this point, previous screen still working (which is fine), because I can see in my log when data is received by TCP component.
The problem is when user hit back buttom (or navigate to "Race" using side menu), the screen itself is re-created and my TCP component is re-created, which I don't want. So my question is: how can I prevent this screen to be re-constructed OR make this TCP component works like a singleton globally? I'm not sure if is possible or how to make it work with Redux.

**Update 1**: This is part of code. In this Race screen, I have this internal function that connect my TCP socket.

```
  _connectSensor() {
    console.log("Running connectSensor function...");
    const { lap_info, dispatchAddLap, dispatchSetSensorStatus } = this.props;
    const { race, sensor } = this.props;

    if (sensor.sensor_status == SENSOR_ONLINE) {
      console.log("Already connected!");
      return;
    }

    dispatchSetSensorStatus(SENSOR_CONNECTING);
    //var serverHost = sensor.host;
    //var serverPort = sensor.port;
    var serverHost = "mydomain.com";
    var serverPort = 1212;
    console.log("Sensor host: ",serverHost);
    console.log("Sensor port: ",serverPort);

    this.client = net.createConnection(serverPort, serverHost, () => {
//      client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
        dispatchSetSensorStatus(SENSOR_ONLINE);
    });

    this.client.on('data', (data) => {      
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);            
      dispatchAddLap(obj);              
    });
```

This function is called by a button and it's working fine. When I go to another screen, this TCP socket still running and feeding data to my Redux, which is the desirable state. But when I got back to this screen (from another one), I can't access this socket anymore.....they still running and I can't stop. When I click "Start", "this.client" is a new object because react-navigation re-create my entire screen (my guess....).
I could put some code to force disconnect when this screen is ummounted....but is not what I need. I need to keep socket receiveing data (if user doesn't stop), even if this screen is not active.

**Update 2**: I have tried to add `static client = null;` to my class object, but doesn't work.
In my "Stop" button, I've added to debug `console.log("Client object:",this.client);` and this is the result:
1) When I open race screen and click 'start', then 'stop', object is returned for 'client'.

2) When I open race screen, click start, goe to another screen, go back to race screen and click "Stop": undefined is returned for 'client' object.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The 'key' for this problem is to export my class as new object, and not just class.
But I had another problem: if I need to use 'connect' from 'react-redux', this doesn't work....simple because 'connect' always return a new object, not the same.
So I made my own ocmponent and create functions to assign dispatchFunctions coming from parent object. This is my final TCP componente:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { SENSOR_ONLINE, SENSOR_OFFLINE, SENSOR_CONNECTING } from "../constants";
var net = require("react-native-tcp");

class tcpCon extends Component {
  static myId;
  static dispatchAddLap;
  static dispatchSetSensorStatus;
  static client;
  static sensor_status = SENSOR_OFFLINE;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("Componente TCP criado! Dados passados: ", props);

    var RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000 + 1);
    this.myId = RandomNumber;
  }

  setDispatchAddLapFunc(func) {
    this.dispatchAddLap = func;
  }

  setDispatchSetSensorStatusFunc(func) {
    this.dispatchSetSensorStatus = func;
  }

  disconnectSensor() {
    console.log("Disconnecting....Status no componente TCP: ", this.sensor_status);
    if (this.sensor_status == SENSOR_ONLINE) {
      this.sensor_status = SENSOR_OFFLINE;
      // Dispatch sensor offline
      if (this.client) {
        console.log("Client object exists. Need to destroy it....");
        this.client.destroy();        
        this.client = null;
      } else {
        console.log("Client doesn't exists");
      }
    }
  }

  displayObj() {
      console.log("Client nesta conexao:",this.client);
  }

  connectSensor(hostname, port) {
    console.log("Running connectSensor function...myId: ", this.myId);

    console.log("Meu status local:", this.sensor_status);

    if (this.sensor_status == SENSOR_ONLINE || this.client) {
      console.log("Connection already exists! Returning....");
      return;
    }

    //var con = net.createConnection(port, hostname, () => {
    this.client = net.createConnection(port, hostname, () => {
      //      client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
      //            dispatchSetSensorStatus(SENSOR_ONLINE);
      //this.client = con;
      this.sensor_status = SENSOR_ONLINE;
      this.dispatchSetSensorStatus(SENSOR_ONLINE);
    });

    this.client.on("data", data => {
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      //console.log("Data arrived: ",obj);
      this.dispatchAddLap(obj);
    });

    this.client.on("error", error => {
      console.log("Erro conectando ao sensor: " + error);
      //          dispatchSetSensorStatus(SENSOR_OFFLINE);
      this.sensor_status = SENSOR_OFFLINE;
      this.dispatchSetSensorStatus(SENSOR_OFFLINE);
    });

    this.client.on("close", () => {
      console.log("Conexão fechada no componente TCP.");
      //          dispatchSetSensorStatus(SENSOR_OFFLINE);
      this.sensor_status = SENSOR_OFFLINE;
      this.dispatchSetSensorStatus(SENSOR_OFFLINE);
    });

    //console.log("Client object na connection:", this.client);


    //this.dispatchAddLap('Hello world!ID '+this.myId.toString());
  }
}

export default new tcpCon();
```

And this is how I call to connect:

```
Con.setDispatchAddLapFunc(dispatchAddLap);
Con.setDispatchSetSensorStatusFunc(dispatchSetSensorStatus)
Con.connectSensor("address",1212);
```

To disconnect, just use this:

```
Con.setDispatchAddLapFunc(dispatchAddLap); // Just to be sure
Con.setDispatchSetSensorStatusFunc(dispatchSetSensorStatus); // Just to be sure
Con.disconnectSensor();
```

With this, anytime that I call this component, the same object is returned.